# I have a json =

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have input json

```json
[
  {
    "nm": "BRANCHID",
    "vl": "1"
  },
  {
    "nm": "TELLERID",
    "vl": "9903"
  },
  {
    "nm": "mobile",
    "vl": "9903234565"
  }
]
```

I  need to check nm equal to `BRANCHID` or `TELLERID` then would set V1 value accordingly  and  output:

```
{"BRANCHID":"1"},
{"TELLERID",:"9903"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Filter by the items you need and then construct a new object combining the `nm` and `vl` attributes:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload 
   filter ((item) -> item.nm == 'BRANCHID' or item.nm == "TELLERID") 
   map ((item) -> {(item.nm) : item.vl})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data into a new object.  There's probably a more sophisticated way to do this, but this should work.

```
let newObj = {};
json.forEach(sort);

function sort(item, index){
    newObj[ json[index].nm ] = json[index].vl;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r75haec8/